# Could you correct these sentences in a grammatically right way?

Tags: grammar

I saw a youtube video and I saw some captions which I felt in certain way awkward.
Of course that's a conversation so there can be some mistakes but as a English learner, I want to get those errors (or maybe not errors, that could be just my mistakes) corrected.

1. It's just part of being a Korean person is : 'is' is neccersary in here?
2. but they're also nice in a certain way which is the ability to make you feel like you're the only person in the room

Comment: ELU isn't supposed to deal with Questions like that. Could you find a WWW tha deals with translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just part of being a Korean person.

But they're also nice in a certain way which is the ability to make you feel like you're the only person in the room. -- correct

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, @surjit! Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer ~ While it is very kind of you to correct the grammar of these sentences for the questioner, EL&U SE discourages proofreading as a rule: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic